# Managing multiple PHP sessions causes script to hang under specific circumstance

Tags: php, session

Running PHP 7.2.12 on a local Apache server (XAMPP on Windows).

I'm playing around with multiple sessions in PHP to see if I can stash away an open session, play around with a new one, and retrieve the previous session. I'm about to give up and just chalk it up to some kind of file locking thing.

The code that hangs ("connection reset" in Firefox):

```
//first session
session_start();
$old_id = session_id();
$old_session = $_SESSION;
$id = session_create_id();
session_commit(); //same as session_write_close()

//new session
session_id($id);
session_name('new_name');
session_start();
```

I don't particularly need any of the code to be this way, but I'm totally lost as to why this hangs due to this:

Comment out any one of the following lines:

```
$old_id = session_id();
$old_session = $_SESSION;
session_name('new_name');
```

And it doesn't hang. You can also replace `session_create_id()` with an alphanumeric string literal and it won't hang. It only seems to hang when all 3 of these optional lines are present, and when using `session_create_id()` to create a new collision free id. Is there a way to guarantee that it won't hang?

And for anyone who has time, I have another question: What would be the proper way to stash an open session, open/manipulate/save my own session, and then restore the original session?

This works:

```
//previous session
session_start();
$_SESSION['var'] = 'value';

//try to stash open session
$old_id = session_id();
session_commit();

//open new session
session_id('mySession');
session_start();

//modify and save my session
$_SESSION['var'] = 'mine';
session_commit();

//restore previous session
session_id($old_id);
session_start();
echo $_SESSION['var']; //output 'value'
```

But I'm afraid that once I start messing with new session names in combo with `session_create_id()` that I'll run into the hanging problem. Maybe I should check for session id collision without the use of `session_create_id()`? Or should I just try to piggy-back onto the already open session?

Edit: Maybe the core of what I'm asking is that if I make a PHP class that wants to pass anonymous data to/from the client, and somebody using my class opened a PHP session prior to using my class, what's the accepted way of handling that without stepping on the previous session? Ideally I want to name my session with something unique to the class, ie. not the default 'PHPSESSID'.

Comment: _“what's the accepted way of handling that without stepping on the previous session?”_ - what “stepping on” are you talking about here? The usual way to go about this is to simply share the _same_ session, not to create multiple ones for the same client that run in parallel …

Comment: I mean stepping on another developer's or script's use of PHP sessions before invoking my class, and overwriting data by accident. I suppose my problem amounts to a namespace issue (which I ended up implementing as `$_SESSION['namespace']['foo']`), so my approach may have been off. I'll leave the question up for now.

Answer (score 0):

You ahe handling Session wrong in first example (you call `session_create_id` uselessly), it probably cause to hanging. Check logs if something info was here.

Maybe problem can be exhalted when you copy $_SESSION variable to another variable and then close session. As PHP internally works it can cause to unpredictable behavion, because $_SESSION is special type of array.